# Pandas не видит запятые в качестве разделителя

Tags: python, pandas

Сохраняю таблицу правильно и указываю сепаратор

[image]

Comment: А что делать с запятыми, использующимися как разделитель целой и дробной части? и самое главное - код и данные в вопросе должны быть в текстовом виде, а не скриншотом.

Comment: Покажите кусок исходного `csv` файла. Подозреваю, что там каждая строка целиком в кавычках. Либо там какая-то нестандартная запятая, в качестве второй версии.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас такой CSV-файл как этот, то вам надо явно сказать Pandas что запятая отделяет дробную часть чисел. По-умолчанию, в Pandas десятичный разделитель - точка. Вы, вероятно, экспортировали файл из Excel на русской версии Windows. Он ставит запятые, так как это стандарт в России:

```
дата,цена,стоимость
01.02.2020,"1,2","2,3"
```

Его надо грузить следующей командой:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',', decimal=',')
#           ----------  -------  -----------
#           ^           ^        десятичный разделитель
#           |           |
#           |           разделитель между полями (можно и опустить)
#           |
#           имя файла
```

> ```
>          дата  цена  стоимость
> 0  01.02.2020   1.2        2.3
> ```